# Dimensionless quantity using fundamental constants

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

Is this quantity dimensionless and a unique construction?

$$\frac{c^7\hbar\varepsilon_0^2}{Ge^4}$$

I used the speed of light, the reduced Planck constant, vacuum permittivity, the gravitational constant and the elementary charge.

If yes, will it be the ultimate universal constant?

Comment: Why would it be the ultimate universal constant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has the value $4.1\times10^{88}\text{ s}^{-2}$ so it isn’t dimensionless: it has the dimensions of inverse time squared. You can rewrite it more simply in terms of the [Planck time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time)

$$t_P=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^5}}$$

and the dimensionless [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant)

$$\alpha=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{\hbar c}$$

as

$$\frac{1}{(4\pi\alpha\,t_P)^2}$$

to make its dimensions obvious.

It isn’t unique and it isn’t “the ultimate universal constant”.

Comment: You're right! So is it not possible to construct a dimensionless quantity that uses c, hbar and G simultaneously ?

Comment: That’s correct.